# Pulled headset wire

Tags: technology

The mic on my headset has stopped working and I think it is because I pulled the wire that connects it from the setting panel halfway up the wire to the headset itself to hard. If I wiggle the wire I can hear something moving on the inside. The headset is a Kotion Each g9000. How do I fix this?

Comment: If the wire is broken or ripped off, the only reasonable thing you can do is buy a new headset. In theory you could open the headset, find the defect in the cable and solder it, but realistically the result will be subpar at best, if it works at all. Most devices are designed in a way that prevents you from opening them without breaking something.

Answer (score 1):

The wires inside most headsets are extremely thin. I have tried to repair some in the past and have only succeeded once. You can try to cut out the dodgy bit and connect the wires up again but my honest opinion would be to buy new ones